# why this javascript has no error in strict mode

Tags: javascript, strict

it is weird that. where "use strict" I place will have different result.
My node version is v9.9.0
I don't understand, would somebody help me

```js
"use strict";

function tryFunction() {
  var tryValue = 123;
  return tryValue;
}
if (true) {
  testvar = 123; // ReferenceError: testvar is not defined
}
```

```js
function tryFunction() {
  var tryValue = 123;
  return tryValue;
}
"use strict";
if (true) {
  testvar = 123;
}

// no errors???
```

```js
function tryFunction() {
  var tryValue = 123;
  return tryValue;
}
if (true) {
  "use strict";
  testvar = 123;
}

// no errors???
```

Comment: "strict mode" only gets triggered at the "top" of a script file, or "top" of a function ... your second two code snippets don't meet this criteria

Comment: Take a look at this to know how to use "use strict".https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Comment: oic, thanks @JaromandaX.

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. the [MDN documentation for strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode):

> Strict mode applies to *entire scripts* or to *individual functions*.

[...]

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the *exact* statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) **before any other statements**.

[...]

> Likewise, to invoke strict mode for a function, put the *exact* statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) in the function's body **before any other statements**.

(Emphasis mine.)

If `"use strict";` appears in the middle of a file or block, it has no effect and is ignored as any other string literal would be.